# Execute with a run time of O(n^3 log n) with 2 loops

Tags: c++

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I just cant get it.  Any help would be great. I'm programming in C++.

Find a run time of O(n^3 log n) using two looping structures.

Comment: `int stop = (int)(n*n*n*log(n));` `for (int c = 0; c < stop; c++);`

Only one loop needed.

Comment: `sleep((int)(n*n*n*log(n)));` No loops needed.

Comment: C++ has nothing to do with it, really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is a homework, here is a hint: you need to put an `O(N*LogN)` operation inside your two nested loops such that the operation does not need a loop.

For example, you can start with an array of `N` items, do nested loops on `i` and `j` that reverse array elements between `i` and `j`, and then sort the resulting array. Reversing is `O(N)`, sorting is `O(N*LogN)`, so sorting dominates; two outer loops provide the remaining `O(N^2)`. Both sorting and reversing can be done using standard library functions, without additional loops.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like almost any sort of complexity can be achieved with really just one looping structure. In your case, something like (pseudo-code):

```
a := 0
b := 0
c := 0
d := 1
WHILE  a < n  OR  b < n  OR  c < n  OR  d < n  LOOP:
    a := a + 1
    IF  a = n  THEN:
        a := 0
        b := b + 1
        IF  b = n  THEN:
            b := 0
            c := c + 1
            IF  c = n  THEN:
                c := 0
                d := d * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably isn't what is required, but just to make a point -- you can do this:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
  for (int j=0; j<n*n*log(n); ++j) {
    x += j;
  }
}
```